# Windows mobile native application do have CSRF?

Tags: mobile, csrf

I developed a windows mobile application which connects back to my web services hosted on internet to sync with the server data.

I didnt put any control for CSRF on mobile application, Is it required to have a CSRF protection on native applications? If yes why?

** My application is native application not on web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it required to have a CSRF protection on native applications?

No, if your mobile application is the only type of consumer (e.g. no web browsers) and your mobile application does not make web requests to other domains then by definition CSRF is not possible as there is no cross site request to counterfeit.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF protection would be on the web server side, not the app, although you can help yourself by setting a cookie from the server on login and adding that cookie to the header of your requests from the native app.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jim B for prompt answer. I am using Jtoken for login management. Beyond this do I need to use CSRF token also?

Answer (score 0):

You application will most likely need to be CSRF aware (if you've implemented protections on the backend).

For instance, a general best practice is to supply a token on each request that will be used on the next request to ensure no duplicate requests can be made. Your mobile app will need to be able to get and use this token (again, assuming you've implemented this on the server side).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends upon if your site can be accessed by a human AND/OR the authentication method that you are using for the web site.

If a user can login in any way to this web site that is hosting your web services via a **browser** then while the user is logged into the site, the answer is yes because CSRF takes advantage of the fact that the browser will send along session and other cookies when the web site is communicated with due to the fact that cookies are automatically added by the browser for all request targeting the same origin regardless of which web site is sending them.

If your web services can be accessed directly via NT Authentication then as long as you are logged into the network, the answer is yes.  The reason is because the attacking web site that is using malicious JavaScript is still accessing the web services as YOU regardless of which site is sending the request.

Finally, if there is absolutely no way to login to the site via a browser and you are not using NT Authentication, SilverlightFox's answer is correct.  The reason is because there would never be a Session cookie for the site so there is nothing to send when the CSRF attack occurred.

**The Fix:**

For web, this is fixed via an anti-forgery token, which is sent back with put and post verbs (although you can do it with all verbs).  A malicious web site could try to send a request and would certainly pickup your session cookie, but the absence of the anti-forgery token in the put/post causes it to fail.

For mobile, patwhite above suggests a fix, but it would require different web service end points for mobile vs web due to the fact that it is a different strategy for handling the problem.